# Wordpress acf repeater get first and second images only

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using acf plugin on a wordpress site. I am using a repeater field with an image subfield that is displayed on a blogpost. My goal is to only get and display the first and second images from a blog post to be displayed for the homepage.

I tried using this code from the acf site documentation but to no avail the code is not working. Can someone know the issue?

```
         <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query ->
            the_post(); 
            $postqID = get_the_ID();
          ?>

          <?php

          $rows = get_field('post_images', $postqID ); // get all the rows
          $first_row = $rows[0]; // get the first row
          $first_row_image = $first_row['post_image' ]; // get the sub field value 

          // Note
          // $first_row_image = 123 (image ID)

          $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $first_row_image, 'full' );
          // url = $image[0];
          // width = $image[1];
          // height = $image[2];
          ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this issue. For those who are also having issues on displaying certain number of rows of images on a repeater field. You can refer my answer.
The code below returns two images from a repeater field. Just changed the condition ($i>1), if you wish to return certain number of image.

```
          <?php

          $i = 0;
          if(get_field('post_images', $postqID)):
          ?>
            <?php while (has_sub_field('post_images',$postqID)): ?>

              <img src="<?php the_sub_field('post_image')['url']; ?>"></img>

            <?php

              $i++;
              if($i > 1)
              {
                break;
              }
            ?>
            <?php  endwhile; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
```